# Retrieve user wise sum cumulative reached records

Tags: php, mysql, database, stored-procedures, cumulative-sum

I have **workouts_data** table which have users cycling details with distance they achieved on daily basis. I would like to get each user records once they crossed 1000 value in distance column and if that user not crossed 1000,then can get max value of records.

I am looking to order record by 1000 reached user and date wise in ascending order,then distance descending order.So then only i can get first achieved user on top and remaining not achieved user next wise versa.

```
Example Data:
Date       User        Distance
1614944833   1           100
1614944232   2           100
1624944831   1           150
1615944832   3           250
1614644836   1           500
1614954835   2           100
1614344834   3           100
1614964831   1           260
1614944238   1           200
```

I have tried with below cumulative sum query,but it not works,

```
select  date,
            sum(distance)  as distance,
            (case when (sum(distance) >= 1000)  
                  THEN  1000  ELSE sum(distance) END) as distance_completed  
from `workouts_data` as `w1` 
where `date` between 1609372800 and 1640995140 
and `w1`.`User` in (1,2,3)  group by `User` 
order by `distance_completed` desc,`date` asc
```

Expected Output

```
Date       User        distance_completed
1614964831   1           1010
1614954835   2           200
1614344834   3           350
```

Can anyone suggest with proper query or stored procedure method?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the sums in that way, you need a outer Select to process the data after grouping

I can't figure out, why you choose these dates, so ou need to check the MAX(`date`) if it fits

> ```
> SELECT 
>     `Date`, `User`, IF(distance_completed > 1000, 1000,distance_completed)  as distance_completed
> FROM (SELECT MAX(`Date`) as 'date', `User`, SUM(`Distance`) AS  distance_completed
> FROM exdata w1
> where `date` between 1609372800 and 1640995140 
> and `w1`.`User` in (1,2,3)  group by `User` ) t1
> order by `distance_completed` desc,`date` asc
> ```
>
> ```
>       Date | User | distance_completed
> ---------: | ---: | -----------------:
> 1624944831 |    1 |               1000
> 1615944832 |    3 |                350
> 1614954835 |    2 |                200
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4ad45ab1f94cea13b1d6e4cdb731a107)*

> ```
> SELECT 
>     `Date`, `User`, IF(distance_completed > 1000, 1000,distance_completed)  as distance_completed
> FROM (SELECT MIN(`Date`) as 'date', `User`, SUM(`Distance`) AS  distance_completed
> FROM exdata w1
> where `date` between 1609372800 and 1640995140 
> and `w1`.`User` in (1,2,3)  group by `User` ) t1
> order by `distance_completed` desc,`date` asc
> ```
>
> ```
>       Date | User | distance_completed
> ---------: | ---: | -----------------:
> 1614644836 |    1 |               1000
> 1614344834 |    3 |                350
> 1614944232 |    2 |                200
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=39f01b1be5fa33cd81713d57ade58384)*

When we add an id you can get the wanted numbers, but  this vital information that should gave been in  the question all along.

> ```
> SELECT 
>     w2.`Date`, t1. `User`, IF(distance_completed > 1000, 1000,distance_completed)  as distance_completed
> FROM (SELECT  `User`, SUM(`Distance`) AS  distance_completed
> FROM workouts_data  w1
> where `date` between 1609372800 and 1640995140 
> and `w1`.`User` in (1,2,3)  group by `User` ) t1 
> inner join (SELECT `Date` , `User` 
> FROM workouts_data  wd2 
> WHERE (id,`User`) IN (SELECT MAX(id),`User` FROM  workouts_data GROUP BY `User`)) w2 ON t1.`User` = w2.`User`
> order by `distance_completed` desc,`date` asc
> ```
>
> ```
>       Date | User | distance_completed
> ---------: | ---: | -----------------:
> 1624944831 |    1 |                950
> 1614344834 |    3 |                350
> 1614954835 |    2 |                200
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1ad17cae79f230f011704e95a6ea646a)*

And an addition for the sum

When you want ti add a row you need a `UNION`

> ```
> (SELECT 
>     w2.`Date`, t1. `User`, IF(distance_completed > 1000, 1000,distance_completed)  as distance_completed
> FROM (SELECT  `User`, SUM(`Distance`) AS  distance_completed
> FROM workouts_data  w1
> where `date` between 1609372800 and 1640995140 
> and `w1`.`User` in (1,2,3)  group by `User`) t1 
> inner join (SELECT `Date` , `User` 
> FROM workouts_data  wd2 
> WHERE (id,`User`) IN (SELECT MAX(id),`User` FROM  workouts_data GROUP BY `User`)) w2 ON t1.`User` = w2.`User`
> order by `distance_completed` desc,`date` asc)
> UNION ALL
> (SELECT 
>     'Count/SUM', SUM(user_count), SUM(IF(distance_completed > 1000, 1000,distance_completed))
> FROM (SELECT  `User`,COUNT(*) as user_count, SUM(`Distance`) AS  distance_completed
> FROM workouts_data  w1
> where `date` between 1609372800 and 1640995140 
> and `w1`.`User` in (1,2,3)  group by `User` )t2)
> ```
>
> ```
> Date       | User | distance_completed
> :--------- | ---: | -----------------:
> 1614954835 |    2 |                200
> 1614344834 |    3 |                350
> 1624944831 |    1 |                950
> Count/SUM  |    8 |               1500
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5a69cc2e546509c73ee79e4d2df8e50c)*

Comment: it works fine,but i need 1614344834 this value in date for user id 3.but it returns first records value 1615944832. –

Comment: then try another like min in m second it is harf´d to guess wjat date you want ad there is no coherent result

Comment: there is no id in the table and no id in the select statement it is only mentioned in the comments.

Comment: if user 1 have reached that target 1000 by 4 records,then user 2 and 3 not reached,then i need to get total number of records of user 1( not after records of  reached target ) reached that target and other users not reached records count also as total,is that possible to get by modifying this query?

Comment: i made three fiddles, to react ti your lack of information, please produce a fiddle with sample data, and show us what you expect from these data

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1ad17cae79f230f011704e95a6ea646a 
records_count -8 ( 4+2+2)    sum_distance - 1500 (950+350+200)
i need result like this from above fiddle.but should not count that after records if user reached target

Comment: that should sufifce

Comment: is that above result possible?

Comment: you see teh dbfiddle and it gives back the shown result, try it ion your own database and see if the resilt fit, i think you need to tweak it still, but when you understand the query you can adept it easily

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239592/discussion-between-user3157334-and-nbk).

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
 select   w1.`user`, 
         case when t1.distance >='1000' 
         then '1000' else t1.distance end as distance,
         t3.date
from workouts_data w1
inner join (
               select   `user`,
                         sum(distance)  as `distance`           
               from `workouts_data`
               where `date` between 1609372800 and 1640995140
               and  `user` in (1,2,3)  
               group by `user`
             ) as t1 on w1.user=t1.user
inner join (
              select `date`,
                      id 
               from workouts_data
               where (id,user) in (select max(id),user from workouts_data group by user)
              ) as t3 on w1.date=t3.date                                  
order by t1.distance  desc;
```

> Result:
>
> ```
> user  distance    date
> 1     1000       1614964831
> 3     350        1614344834
> 2     200        1614954835
> ```

Demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7yUJcuMJPncBBnrExKbzYz/164

Comment: is there possible to get along with date of last records in this query?  for user id 3, can i get 1614344834? like i mentioned in above expected output

Comment: @user3157334 Does the table have an `id` autoincrement ?

Comment: yes,the table have an id autoincrement

Comment: I want to sum total number of records to reach this target from each user with this query and sum that count,same sum for distance also,is that possible in this query?